# A bad question is used as example of good question in the help center

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I was reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the help center of StackOverflow and found this as a *good* example of a question:

> **Good:** Why does str == "value" evaluate to false when str is set to "value"?

I tend to participate in Java Q/As and a question like this would be automatically downvoted and closed for being a duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1065197)

And this repeats for other programming languages as well:

- C#: [Differences in string compare methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44288/1065197)
- Python: [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/1065197)
- Perl: [How do I compare two strings in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1175390/1065197)
- C++: [How to compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6222583/1065197)
- C: [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004237/1065197)
- JavaScript: [What is the correct way to check for string equality in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3586775/1065197), [Why does ("foo" === new String("foo")) evaluate to false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10951906/1065197), [How do you do string comparison in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51165/1065197)

(and on and on...)

I think this example should be changed. For example, a example of bad/good question would be:

- Bad: cannot connect to database
- Good: Why the database connection doesn't open if I provide the right credentials?

Open to other ideas to replace this example.

Comment: So if you post a great question, and then someone else posts a duplicate, are they both bad now?

Comment: I don't really think it's a bad question just because there are duplicates. Pretty much all simple example questions which are valid have been asked before here at this point. As long as the help center also explains that you shouldn't post dupes, I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @SamIam no, but this specific case is not a good question for the site anymore.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza and what would suggest? Would you prefer they do it purely in rational algebra? example:

*Good* : Why does problem A exist when I operation B?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That specific section of the help center is merely discussing how to write a descriptive title that accurately explains the question being asked.  It's not discussing the on-topic-ness of these example questions, nor is *that particular section* discussing doing sufficient research.  There *is* a section that mentions that; it's the section just before this one.

Trying to use particularly complex questions (that would represent questions that are harder to research answers to) is only going to over complicate the point that that section is trying to make.  It would draw attention away from the clarity and descriptiveness of the title by overemphasizing other topics.

Were the help center to have a complete example question designed to exemplify *all* of the points mentioned *then* this would be an important consideration.

Comment: I suppose perhaps maybe a tip or info message on that help topic to let them know that the "actual topic of the question maybe be duplicate, as such would not be a good question" or perhaps just one of those disclaimers:

DISCLAIMER: "Examples listed may display traits of **Bad** questions"

Comment: @Mike Given that the users will have just finished reading the section on doing sufficient research mere seconds before looking at these examples, it seems rather unnecessary to repeat it again half a screen length later.  Each of these points need to be as concise and understandable as possible.  Adding in a text like that would likely hamper, not help, the quality of this resource.

Comment: I agree completely, this isn't really an issue but if people were to make it one, I was just proposing a solution. Although I don't believe this is even necessary.